# combining two different record into single result

Tags: mysql, php

I am fetching data from 3 tables with the help of join. My output is in JSON format.

***Output in JSON format:-***

```
{"order_id":"2", 
 "location_address":"Testing location Delhi",
 "emp_first_name":"**Ranjeet**",
 "order_status":"0",
 "from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
 "actions":"\r\n <\/i> Edit <\/a>\r\n \r\n <\/i> Delete <\/a>"},

{"order_id":"2",
"location_address":
"Testing location Delhi",
"emp_first_name":"**abhijeet**",
"order_status":"0",
"from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
"actions":"\r\n <\/i> Edit <\/a>\r\n \r\n <\/i> Delete <\/a>"},
```

The problem is, In above output, All the data is same but emp_first_name are different because both are having seperate id's. Now i want to combine the data of both the emp_first_name and display it as single output like

***The output which i want :-***

```
{"order_id":"2",
 "location_address":"Testing location Delhi",
 "emp_first_name":"**Ranjeet,abhijeet**",
 "order_status":"0",
 "from_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
 "actions":"\r\n <\/i> Edit <\/a>\r\n \r\n <\/i> Delete <\/a>"},
```

***QUery I Used :-***

```
$this->datatables
   ->select('o.order_id, 
        concat_ws(" " , `l.location_street`, `l.location_city` ) as location_address, 
        e.emp_first_name, o.order_status, o.from_date')
   ->from('orders o')
   ->join('location l', 'o.location_id = l.location_id')
   ->join('order_details od', 'od.order_id = o.order_id')
   ->join('employee e', 'e.emp_id = od.emp_id');
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `GROUP_CONCAT` on `emp_first_name`. Maybe something like:

```
$this->datatables
   ->select('o.order_id, 
        concat_ws(" " , `l.location_street`, `l.location_city` ) as location_address, 
        group_concat(e.emp_first_name SEPARATOR ','), o.order_status, o.from_date')
   ->from('orders o')
   ->join('location l', 'o.location_id = l.location_id')
   ->join('order_details od', 'od.order_id = o.order_id')
   ->join('employee e', 'e.emp_id = od.emp_id')
   ->group_by('o.order_id');
```

Comment: The group_by gets rid of the dup rows of output.